# Firebug is printing one addtional numbers when executing code in its command line

Tags: javascript, firebug

I was executing JavaScript within Firebug's console. While running the below loop I have noticed it's printing one additional number:

```
var i = 0; 

while(i<10) {
  console.log(i);
  i++;
}
```

It's providing the following output:

```
var i = 0;   while(i<10) {   console.log(i);   i++; } 
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
9
```

Is this a bug or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [*Console* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel) outputs the return values of scripts executed through the [Command Line](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line) or the [Command Editor](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Editor). Unfortunately Firebug does not visually differentiate the return value from the output created through `console.log()`. So the second `9` at the end of the output is the return value.
Within the Firefox [built-in DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) this is more obvious:

[image: Display of return value of command line expression in built-in DevTools]

Note that the output of the return value cannot be suppressed.

Comment: And to be clear, the return value of the script is the value of the last statement executed, namely `i++` where `i = 9` (which returns 9 because of postfix increment).

Answer (score 0):

The last `9`, which is causing disturbance, is the return value of `console.log()`. Try `alert(i)` instead of `console.log(i)`.

Comment: Hello Sebastian Zartner,|
My question was why it is happening with console.log?? Not to use some other way to escape the error. Intention is to dig deep why it is happening and how to resolve it. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: This answer is from ozil, my one is above.